# openni_kinect installation issues with configuration

Tags: ros, openni, nite, openni-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have ubuntu 10.10. I am encountering the following errors when i try to install openni-kinect. It says that

```
ros-diamondback-openni-kinect is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0B of additional disk space will be used.
```

When say yes to this. I get the below error.
I see that openni-dev, nite-dev, ps-engine and ros-diamondback-openni-kinect are depended on each other. I followed the instructions in http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect which says New in diamond pack. So i am not sure if the configurations are to be done in packages or in my end. Can somebody tell me how to configure (i see this is the only problem) them so as to complete my installation. Thanks in advance.

```
 Setting up openni-dev (1.1.0.41~maverick) ...
Failed: Failed to write to the file!
dpkg: error processing openni-dev (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 255
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nite-dev:
 nite-dev depends on openni-dev (>= 1.1.0.41~maverick); however:
  Package openni-dev is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing nite-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ps-engine:
 ps-engine depends on openni-dev (>= 1.1.0.41~maverick); however:
  Package openni-dev is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing ps-engine (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ros-diamondback-openni-kinect:
 ros-diamondback-openni-kinect depends on ps-engine; however:
  Package ps-engine is not configured yet.
 ros-diamondback-openni-kinect depends on nite-dev; however:
  Package nite-dev is not configured yet.
 ros-diamondback-openni-kinect depends on openni-dev; however:
  Package openni-dev is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing ros-diamondback-openni-kinect (--configure):
 dependency probNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                            No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                          lems - leaving unconfigured


**Errors were encountered while processing:
 openni-dev
 nite-dev
 ps-engine
 ros-diamondback-openni-kinect
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)**
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10931/openni_kinect-installation-issues-with-configuration/) by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2831 on 2011-08-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This should just work - I'm guessing that something got out of sync on your machine somehow. I would remove those packages, `sudo apt-get update`, and reinstall `ros-diamondback-openni-kinect`.

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) with karma: 4336 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2011-10-12**:
Ya, I did open another question, but forgot to update the same here. Here is the link to another question http://answers.ros.org/question/2411/kinect-not-detected

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-10-12**:
You should open another question, also search for that solution elsewhere.  I know there are other questions with that error already.

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2011-09-27**:
This solution only solves the Errors encountered in the question but does not help in getting started with Kinect. I see "No devices connected" error when i try to launch the openni_node.launch file.

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2011-09-27**:
I found some solution in this link "http://groups.google.com/group/openni-dev/browse_thread/thread/bcd013333abc9553/c307a8edcdaa5648?lnk=gst&q=Not+able+to+register+modules+#c307a8edcdaa5648" where creating ni folder before installation in /var/lib/ helps niReg.

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2011-09-07**:
Hi Patrick, i just did the same but the error is recurring.